# How to redirect after mail send with PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

How can I redirect when the email is being sent with PHPMailer?

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; 
// $mail->Host       = "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
$mail->Host       = "email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com";
$mail->Username   = "AKIAIVSF45PCGR7NZWNQ";
$mail->Password   = "Am2SBg4vluOvIc1+kycsWpCnxtf3jhGjYCAdBv7YYp/y";
//

$mail->SetFrom('test@gmail.com', 'Z-Reports'); //from (verified email address)
$mail->Subject = "Z-Reports (sent via smtp)"; //subject

//message
$body = emailZReports($total_sales, $inventory);

// $body = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
//

//recipient
$mail->AddAddress("test@gmail.com", "Z-Reports"); 

//Success
if ($mail->Send()) { 
    echo "Message Sent!";            
}

//Error
if(!$mail->Send()) { 
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo; 
}
```

How can I redirect to a specific page instead of displaying `Message Sent!`?

Comment: This code will send a message twice, and it looks like it's based on a *very* old and obsolete example, so make sure you're using [the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Answer (score 5):

if you are using SMTP, you can't redirect to another page if `$mail->SMTPDebug` is not set to 0. This is because it sends out headers which you can't modify with `header("Location: path/to/redirect")`.  Set  `$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;` so that you can redirect to another page after `$mail->send()`. but you have to do that only when you have finished debugging and your mail is sending successfully.

Comment: Thank you dude. You saved my time

Comment: I just looked at the question. I wish I could help out but I've not used such like that before.

Comment: thanks.. I have figured out the solution, will post here once I am free

Answer (score 2):

You can use php `header` function

```
//Success
    if ($mail->Send()) { 
        header("Location:Yourfile.php");//echo "Message Sent!";            
    }
```

Make sure there is not `echo` or any `output` before this function

Comment: thanks @B. Desai, i'll try it .. is there more way for returning?

Comment: What issue are you getting? Will you edit your question with updated code?

Comment: i'd added my returnpage.php file to the header, and it only gives me blank white screen

Comment: `header("Location: returnpage.php");` ?

Comment: header("Location:dashboard/store/merchant/z-reports.twig");

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't want to point directly at a twig template; the page should be rendered by a PHP script from that template.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this,

See [Header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) for more info.
It can be like this,

```
//Success
    if ($mail->Send()) { 
        header('Location: nextpage.php');            
    }
```

Otherwise, you can use Javascript to redirect the user.

Just use

```
window.location = "http://www.nextpage.com/"
```

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo "Message could not be sent.  ";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit; 
 } //echo getcwd(); 
header("Location:index.php") //redirects to a page named index.php;
```

Answer (score 0):

// make another script for redirecting

```
<?php
require_once("mail_function.php");
if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
header("Location: form.php");exit; //redirect to form submit page
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
header("Location: index.php");exit; //redirect to your home page
}
?>
```

//mail_function.php

```
<?php
require 'class/class.phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Mailer   = "smtp";
$mail->SetFrom("xxxx@gmail.com", "web");
$mail->Port = '587';                //Sets the default SMTP server port
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                     //Sets SMTP authentication.
$mail->Username = 'xxxx@gmail.com';                 //Sets SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'xxxx';                   //Sets SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';               //Sets connection prefix.
$mail->FromName = $_POST["name"];
$mail->AddAddress($email);          //Adds a "To" address
$mail->AddCC($_POST["email"], $_POST["name"]);  //Adds a "Cc" address
$mail->WordWrap = 50;           //Sets word wrapping on the body
$mail->IsHTML(true);                    //Sets message type to HTML 
$mail->Subject = "somthing";
$mail->MsgHTML($message_body);
$mail->Body = "somthing";
$result = $mail->Send();
return $result;
?>
```

Comment: it would be nice if you add some explanation